# Why does my oscillator circuit + class AB power amplifier circuit not work?

Tags: ac, ltspice, oscillator, class-ab

I am trying to design a oscillator circuit + class ab power amplifier for my circuit. I tried simulation on ltspice but it did not manage to work. I have problem figuring out what is wrong with my circuit.

Below is my ltspice circuit:
[image]

By running it, it shows that I have a DC input and output.

[image]

However if I run the class AB power amplifier with schottky diode, it will work but only conduct the positive half of the circuit.

[image]

What I dont get is that with schottky diodes I get AC input and output but with regular diodes I get only DC input and output.
Is there any suggestion so that I can have both AC input and output + conduct for both positive and negative cycles?

Comment: What happens if you AC couple your output load?  Also you should label your node names when posting the schematic and plots so we know what we’re looking at. Kind of hard to know what N004 and N005 are.

Comment: Why is the buffer biased towards GND? Is the oscillator starting reliably, and if not, add a step source in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to drive the output negative (below ground) but you don't have a negative supply. The AC signal you show has negative excursions to the waveform because of capacitive coupling and level shifting.

Comment: The signal shouldn't go from 0 to 20V in that case? I don't clearly see how it only outputs negative voltages

Comment: AIUI, the circuit outputs only the positive portion, and not negative.

Answer (score 2):

With a complementary-symmetry push-pull amplifier like that the output should be at half the supply voltage with no signal, and then vary above and below that with an AC signal.

With your 20 V supply that puts it at 10 VDC with respect to ground, so your 100\$\Omega\$ load resistor will have 10 VDC across it and 100 mA through it with no signal.

There are two ways this is dealt with, either use a dual polarity supply with the NPN's collector to positive and the PNP's collector to negative and the bias resistors adjusted so the DC on the output is at the same potential as ground, or with a single supply you have to capacitively couple the output to remove the DC component.

Some advantages of using a bipolar supply are that the amplifier is DC coupled so you can amplify DC as well as AC signals, for example you can have a sine wave with a DC offset, and it eliminates the need for a large capacitor on the output which generally means an electrolytic.

Comment: For that to work, the bias resistors R3 and R4 should be equal. With R3 about 13 times R4, the output would be at  DC level about Vcc/13, or about 20/13 = 1.5 VDC, which it seems to be, assuming V(n005) is the output.

Comment: @PStechPaul Yes, of course you would have to adjust the bias for 0 VDC at the output.